# tqdm progressbar and colorama do not work together

Tags: python, tqdm, colorama

I want to use colorama, but I already use tqdm in my code.

Example:

```
import colorama as color
import tqdm as tqdm  # without line it's working
print(color.Fore.GREEN + 'Green text')
```

It's working fine without tqdm, but if I import tqdm, colorama does not color the text until I restart the console. I use IPython console with Spyder (Python 3.6).

Is there a way I can use these packages together?

Answer (score 2):

try it as follow (https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm/issues/450)

```
from tqdm import trange
from colorama import Fore
for i in trange(int(7e7),
    bar_format="{l_bar}%s{bar}%s{r_bar}" % (Fore.GREEN, Fore.RESET)):
    pass
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import colorama as color
import tqdm as tqdm 
import os

os.system('cls')
print(color.Fore.GREEN + 'Green text')
```

tqdm doesn't works if there is any other activity going on or was previously run on your terminal.

so its better to once clear your terminal screen at the starting of your code using os.system('cls') .
This works fine for me.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now.

Answer (score 0):

If you include the "**colour**" optional parameter in tqdm, it uses that color for the progress bar and then the following colored text, as far as I saw is printed as expected but **not every text** is colored. I didn't investigate yet what the logic is but that parameter changes further printing.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve this problem by:
`import sys` and adding as the first line after imports `sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__`.

```
import sys
sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
```

This get back colors and also `tqdm` is workint. I do not use COLORAMA but I use directly ansi escape sequences directly. 
I tried this approach since I read that `tqdm` redirects stdout to stderr, and it worked. 
The value of `sys.__stdout__` would be the initial value of stdout when the script is just opened. Importing `tqdm` redirects it. :)