# importing tqdm disables text formatting using termcolor

Tags: python, python-3.x, terminal, pycharm, tqdm

I think my problem is parallel to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43097262/tqdm-progressbar-and-colorama-do-not-work-together)

I'm using termcolor to format terminal text. `termcolor` basically just wraps your string in ANSI codes that the terminal then interprets. The snippet

```
from termcolor import cprint

cprint('Hello, World!', 'green', attrs=['bold'])
```

[image: green text]

works fine, but importing tqdm results in white text:

```
from tqdm import tqdm
from termcolor import cprint
cprint('Hello, World!', 'green', attrs=['bold'])
```

[image: white text]

The ANSI codes are still there, but the terminal is no longer parsing them.

`tqdm` is unfortunately deeply entrenched in my package, so I can't just get rid of the import. What is the package doing to the terminal that changes the behavior, and how can I disable it when I need to?

Using python 3.5, tqdm 4.15, PyCharm 2017.2.3 on Windows 10

Comment: works for me in MacOS, something wrong with windows? tqdm did nothing magic, merely do line overwrite by print `\r`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was not with `tqdm`, but with `colorama` which is used internally. On Windows / PhCharm there are known issues with the `colorama.init()` method (see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-16927, https://github.com/tartley/colorama/issues/79)

Fortunately, as long as you use `.init(strip=False)` everything works fine, and the `colorama` folks have provided a convenient `.deinit()` method to reverse whatever `tqdm` uses on import. The following works:

```
from tqdm import tqdm
import colorama
from termcolor import cprint

colorama.deinit()
colorama.init(strip=False)
cprint('Hello, World!', 'green', attrs=['bold'])
```